# conditionals and arrays in C (beginner)

Tags: c, arrays, io, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Although I've been sitting on this topic for months, I'm relatively new to C.  I'm trying to write a simple question/response program.  I know it has something to do with the if else conditions (everything else works), but I've searched and can't seem to find the problem.  There's also the recursion at the end that repeats the program.  The function call that I put inside of it might be wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char line[100];
    char decision[100];
    printf("Are you gonna throw it?\n");
    printf("Type yes or no.\n");

    scanf("%s", line);
    printf("%s \n", line);

    if (line == "yes") {
        printf("Thanks.\n");
    } else if (line == "no") {
        printf("Why not?\n");
    }

    printf("Do you want to do this again?\n");
    scanf("%s", decision);
    if (decision == "yes") {
        main();
    };
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  The idea of comparing the strings hadn't come to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparisons like `line == "yes"` doesn't work.
You need to compare your string using strcmp, e.g.

```
if (strcmp(line, "yes") == 0) {
    printf("Thanks.\n");
} else if (strcmp(line, "no") == 0) {
    printf("Why not?\n");
}
```

Comment: And if you want to ignore case `strcasecmp()`

Answer (score 1):

To compare strings, you have to use `strcmp` or `strncmp` function from string.h

Other problem is:

`main` should return `int`.

`int main()`

OR

`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Or equivalent is the proper signature for main in C.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not necessary in this case and builds up data on the stack unnecessarily for each iteration of the program.  Enclose your entire code in a `do {...} while (strcmp(decision, "yes") == 0)` loop instead.  Also change `line == "yes"` and `line == "no"` to `strcmp(line, "yes") == 0` and `strcmp(line, "no") == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know: string literals like `"yes"` and `"no"` are *array expressions*; the *expression* `"yes"` has type "4-element array of `char`" (1 extra for the 0 terminator).

Second thing to know: in most circumstances, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you write `if (line == "yes")`, both of the expressions `line` and `"yes"` are converted from type "array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and their values are the addresses of their first element, *which will be different* (even if the contents of `line` are `"yes"`, the *string literal* `"yes"` lives at a different address from `line`).  Thus the comparison always fails, regardless of the contents of `line`.

In order to compare the *contents* of the two array expressions, you will need to use the standard library function `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(line, "yes") == 0) { ... }
```

`strcmp` will return 0 if the two strings are equivalent, < 0 if `line` is *lexicographically* less than `"yes"`, and > 0 if `line` is lexicographically greater than `"yes"`.

Answer (score 0):

1) remove the semicolon here:

```
if (decision == "yes")
{
     main();
 }; //<-- if you want to keep this code at all
```

2) you can't compaire strings using ==

```
strcmp(decision, "yes"); //returns 0 if they are equil
```

3) why recursivly call main()? Why not just put the whole thing in a loop:

```
main() { 
  char line[100];
  char decision[100] = "yes";
  while(!strcmp(decision, "yes")){
    printf("Are you gonna throw it?\n"); 
    printf("Type yes or no.\n");
    scanf("%s", line);  
    printf("%s \n", line);  
    if (!strcmp(line, "yes"))
      printf("Thanks.\n");   
    else if (!strcmp(line, "no"))     
      printf("Why not?\n");   

    printf("Do you want to do this again?\n");
    scanf("%s", decision); 
  } //end while
} //end main
```